# "'iso-8859-1' is not a supported encoding name" exception while Decompress compressed string in Silverlight 5 using DotNetZip (Ionic.Zlib)

Tags: silverlight, iso-8859-1, dotnetzip

I have WCF Service, consumed by Silverlight client. In the service I create a string (which is representing a `.csv` file) and I compress it. When I try to decompress it on the client I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'iso-8859-1' is not a supported encoding name.
>   Parameter name: name
>   at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
>   at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
>   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
>   at Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream..cctor()}

I didn't manage to find any info about what is causing this and how to be avoided. I'll be grateful for any help!

The code used is the following:

Service:

```
private static byte[] Zip(string str)
{
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        using (var msInput = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var msOutput = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(msOutput, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                msInput.CopyTo(gs);             
            }

            return msOutput.ToArray();
        }
}
```

Silverlight client:

```
private void UnzipToTheExportStream(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (_exportStream)
    {
        using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gs.CopyTo(_exportStream);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is happening upon the initialization of the `GZipStream`. For decompression I use DotNetZip (`Ionic.Zlib`). For compression I tried both DotNetZip and `System.IO.Compression` (which is not available in Silverlight) but with same result

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! At least for my case.

I have noticed that the nuget package contained 3 DLLs (Ionic.BZip2.dll/Ionic.Zip.dll/Ionic.Zlib.dll).

I have compared `Ionic.Zip` and `Ionic.Zlib` in Assemply Explorer.
[image: Comparison of 2 DLLs in the Assembly Explorer]

The problem was solved by replacing the reference that I had from `Ionic.Zlib` to `Ionic.Zip`

Also, if you decompile "GZipStream" using ReSharper in the code above when you have reference to `Ionic.Zlib` and when you have reference to `Ionic.Zip` you will notice some difference in "usings". The first one does not have 
`using Ionic.Encoding;` 
which explains everything :)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri, I havent tried this, but by the time I asked the question, I didn't manage to find a solition, so I used another third party library which was working:

https://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/